# How to list all incoming requests to istio gateway?

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I want to see all the incoming requests to my istio gateway for debugging reasons. Where do I find it?

I am expecting something like nginx logs.

I am using

```
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use Istio default gateway implementation
```

Comment: Can you share for which object that spec is?

Comment: Its the gateway `kubectl get gateway -o yaml -n istio-system`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the logs of the istio-ingressgateway pod by running the following command:

$ kubectl -n istio-system logs $(kubectl -n istio-system get pods
-listio=ingressgateway -o=jsonpath="{.items[0].metadata.name}") --tail=300

It shows what happens with last 300 incoming requests and possible errors.

More debugging commands can be found in this [blog article](https://blog.jayway.com/2018/10/22/understanding-istio-ingress-gateway-in-kubernetes/). I hope it helps.

Comment: I wanted a list of all the incoming requests like `GET /api/posts`. Instead this gives me `[2019-09-18 03:56:08.702][15][warning][config] [bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/external/envoy/source/common/config/_virtual_includes/grpc_stream_lib/common/config/grpc_stream.h:87] gRPC config stream closed: 13,`

Answer (score 0):

Building on the previous answer and its feedback, I've followed a portion of this [example](https://istio.io/docs/examples/bookinfo/) application and I've successfully obtained the `Ingress` logs for HTTP requests with the following:

```
ingress_pod=$(kubectl get pods --namespace istio-system -l istio=ingress -o=jsonpath="{.items[0].metadata.name}")
kubectl logs $ingress_pod --namespace istio-system | grep -e '\] "GET'
```

You can also obtain the "East/West" HTTP traffic by obtaining the logs of the [Envoy](https://www.envoyproxy.io/learn/service-mesh#envoy-as-a-sidecar)  Sidecar with:

```
kubectl logs -l app=productpage,version=v1 --container=istio-proxy --namespace=default --tail 10000 | grep -e '\] "GET'
```

Feel free to modify the HTTP verbs in the `grep` commands's expressions along with the labels and namespaces accordingly.

Comment: Empty grep result. Didnt work for me. The gateway is up. My servers are working.

Comment: Can you tell how you installed istio and what's the kubernetes cluster set up?